# D3js dynamically attach circles into a line with drag and drop

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am very new to d3js v3 and I was trying out a new program where there are lines and the according to the data, circles get embedded into them.

This is what I have so far.

```js
var width = 500,
  height = 500;

var animals = ['dog', 'cat', 'bat'];
var fruits = ['apple', 'banana'];


var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var line1 = svg.append("line")
  .attr("x1", 350)
  .attr("y1", 5)
  .attr("x2", 350)
  .attr("y2", 350)
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("stroke", "black");

var line2 = svg.append("line")
  .attr("x1", 80)
  .attr("y1", 5)
  .attr("x2", 100)
  .attr("y2", 350)
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("stroke", "black");

var animal_scale = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(animals)
  .rangePoints([5, 350],.2);

var fruit_scale = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(fruits)
  .rangePoints([5, 350],.2);


var animal_circles = svg.selectAll('circle')
  .data(animals)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', function(d) {
    // is there a way to calc it automatically according to line 1
  })
  .attr('cy', function(d) {
    return animal_scale(d);
  })
  .attr('id', function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .attr('r', 20);

var fruits_circles = svg.selectAll('circle')
  .data(fruits)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', function(d) {
    // is there a way to calc it automatically according to line 2
  })
  .attr('cy', function(d) {
    return fruit_scale(d);
  })
  .attr('id', function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .attr('r', 20);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset=utf-8>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

I looked at some sources and being new, its kinda hard to understand most of it. I eventually want to be able to move and drag the circles between lines at the end of the project.There are some issues with the current code, as it does not display the second set of circles too.

Could someone please help me understand further how to do this. It would be a great way for me to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You can select objects by class name and set data. Here is my fast solution for drag-n-drop: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tomatetz/powp6Leh/1/). You can modify `drag` function to add limits to `cx` position